# SELECT * INTO newtable not working

Tags: db2, ddl, select-into

So in Db2/IBM Data Studio I am unable to run this:

```
SELECT * 
INTO newtable 
FROM oldtable
```

I am getting this error message:

> The "newtable" is not valid in the context where it is used..sqlcode=-206 sqlstate=42703, driver=3.68.61.

The table newtable does not exist already.
I researched the sqlcode, sqlstate
- [IBM error code resolve](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n206.html), 
but it didn't help.

To clarify I want to make a copy of the oldtable as a new table newtable.

I know there are alternate ways to do this same thing but this one is the simplest and I'm wondering why it's not working.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's not working because such syntax is incorrect.

Comment: @mustaccio [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp) is where I found the syntax. What do you think is correct?

Comment: Why would anyone down vote this and not leave a comment

Comment: Consider using product documentation (for your specific Db2 version and platform) as a reference; SQL dialects differ between DBMSes.

Comment: Another good example why w3fools is not a resource to rely on. That is not even close to standard SQL. In standard SQL (and [in DB2 as well](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000927.html?pos=2)) you need to use `create table newtable as select * from oldtable`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That doesn't work either. I can only make a new empty table (WITH NO DATA) and then insert data with INSERT INTO

Comment: You need to be using Db2 11.1 to use the WITH DATA clause

Comment: No thats not correct @P.Vernon. Its available in earlier versions as well. I use it  (V7.3 )

Comment: I was assuming Db2 for LUW (Linux, Unix, Windows). V.7.3 is Db2 for i. They are different products and have different version numbers

Answer (score 2):

Select into is for SQL Server (or orther in dont know). For DB2 instruction for save query into table is :

```
create table newtable as (
SELECT * FROM oldtable
) with data
```

You can find more options [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzhctabl.htm)